# Template for cards/checklists for cards created by received emails

Tags: trello

I've been looking around for a way to create templates for cards/checklist on Trello.

My problem is as follows:

- As I create cards automatically through emails, I can't use the copy cards/checklists technique to create/use an already used cards/checklists.

Is there a way for the following action: "Each card (which contains checklist) created via received email has the same template"?